# Wrong argument type listp, "GIF" When reverse a list

Tags: lisp, elisp, sicp

I write such a function to reverse a list

Exercise 2.18.  Define a procedure reverse that takes a list as argument and returns a list of the same elements in reverse order:

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :session sicp :lexical t
(defun reversex(item)
  (cond
   ((null item) nil)
   ((cons (reversex (cdr item))
          (car item)))
   ))
(reversex (list 1 4 9 16 25))
#+end_src
```

Got the following output on the first run:

```
#+RESULTS:
: (((((nil . 25) . 16) . 9) . 4) . 1)
```

But the second run, get an error:

```
  Wrong argument type listp, "GIF"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear where that "GIF" is coming from, because you didn't provide the input for the "second run" you mention. Anyway, your algorithm for reversing a list is incorrect, you're supposed to build a *proper list* as output, and this is not it:

```
(((((nil . 25) . 16) . 9) . 4) . 1)
```

It should look like this:

```
'(25 . (16 . (9 . (4 . (1 . nil)))))
```

Here's one way to do it - using an accumulator parameter. Also notice how the `else` condition for a `cond` should be written:

```
(defun reversex (lst acc)
  (cond
    ((null lst) acc)
    (t (reversex (cdr lst) (cons (car lst) acc)))))

(reversex '(1 4 9 16 25) nil)
=> (25 16 9 4 1)
```

Comment: sicp is amazing, I find my wrong solution is  the Exercise 2.22 which exposure a bug as an exercise.